# How to get the referral website url in Sanic

Tags: python-3.x, request, sanic

I am trying to get the referral website URL/server name (not the IP address) from the incoming request in Sanic. However, so far, I have managed to get the IP and port of the connection from the request header. Is there any python package or built-in functionality in Sanic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
referrer = request.headers.get("Referer")  # url
u = urlparse(referrer)
print(u.netloc)  # server name
```

Docs for Referer header - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer
Docs for urlparse - https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse

Comment: Okay. I am gonna check it in two hours. Thanks